# Issues with pip failing to install some modules (while successful with some others)…what else can I try, do I need a venv?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, python-module, python-venv

I have Python 3.8.2 (latest) installed on a Big Sur macOS M1 Mac mini and it's installed into the Command Line Tools directory `(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework)`.

I've been attempting to load various python 3 packages/modules using various methods as recommended in the official docs, here on SO and elsewhere.

Some modules load and some fail to complete the installation (see below for example error details), whatever syntax I use to invoke the download and installation.

Should I attempt to work around these issue with a Virtual Environment (adding complication as I'm pretty new to Python)?

If the answer is "yes, you should be using a `venv` to solve this", should I use a high level tool like pipenv as [recommended here in HHGtP](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) or a lower level tool like `venv` or `virtualenv` as [recommended in the offical docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/)?

---

**Background**:

Modules which successfully installed and I can import in the REPL:

- numpy.    ✓
- openpyxl  ✓ <— Installed into my user folder
- pyexcel    ✓ <— In user folder
- superpower ✓
- urllib3    ✓
- xlrd       ✓
- xlwt       ✓

Modules that failed to install:

- matplotlib  ❌    imports in python3 REPL though so seems to be good
- mpl_toolkits ❌   imports in python3 REPL though so seems to be good
- netCDF4 ❌
- opt_debug  ❌  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opt_debug (from versions: none)
- pylab   ❌  Could not find a version that satisfies
- pyproj  ❌
- PyQt5   ❌
- shutil  ❌

I've downloaded a Python project from GitHub called [SIREN](https://github.com/ozsolarwind/siren) that I am  attempting to build for macOS (with the assistance of the author of SIREN who uses Linux and Windows but not macOS). It has a number of module dependencies outside Python 3's standard library, in addition to many of its own modules in the project files (the project modules load ok in the Python 3 REPL but many external dependancies don't).

Almost always the modules attempt to install in my user folder, not in the CLT base installation of Python due to a write protect error in the install process. I know it's recommended not to, but in desperation I even attempted to use $`sudo python3 -m pip install PyQt5` and although it spend a few minutes attempting to install it ultimately failed with some kind of metadata error. (see below).

These commands indicate I have the tools installed and path is operating well enough for them to operate:

`$ python3 --version`

> Python 3.8.2

`$ python3 -m pip --version`

> pip 22.0.4 from /Users/me/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Here's some examples of failure errors:

```
$ pip install PyQt5
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable Collecting PyQt5
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
   
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [29 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/alastairleith/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/alastairleith/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/alastairleith/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/alastairleith/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "/private/var/folders/f3/0sr9wxg16l3dbxncx0fjdz6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-51w_hx87/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "/private/var/folders/f3/0sr9wxg16l3dbxncx0fjdz6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-51w_hx87/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "/private/var/folders/f3/0sr9wxg16l3dbxncx0fjdz6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-51w_hx87/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 594, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/f3/0sr9wxg16l3dbxncx0fjdz6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-51w_hx87/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/f3/0sr9wxg16l3dbxncx0fjdz6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-51w_hx87/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "/private/var/folders/f3/0sr9wxg16l3dbxncx0fjdz6m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-51w_hx87/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed

  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
   ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for details.
```

When pip3 fails to install in one instance and when I check `pip3 --version` I get told to read this note
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
it warns against using sudo so I avoided it for some time yesterday but eventually gave in to temptation. It ran the install process for PyQt5 for a few minutes and did lots of downloading but the installation failed also. I’m not sure if it tried to install in the home directory of python 3 or in my user folder, don't recall. I tried to uninstall after it failed.

Comment: It is best practice to always use a virtual environment for your Python projects, rather than installing directly to the Python installation's site-packages. With a venv, you can then be sure you install all the packages you need in the _same place_, and you run your app using the modules from the _same env_, and all using the _same Python version_. It can indeed be a complication when you are just starting, but your future self will thank your past self for taking the time to get used to it.

Comment: I created a venv using pipenv and seemed to go well. when I then used `pipenv install PyQt5` it failed with the same types of error message. Having seen your comment now @GinoMempin I will try and remove that pipenv instance and start again with `venv`

Comment: Well, at least with a virtual environment, you can now isolate that it's probably not an env problem, but a most likely a package problem.

Comment: I have a bunch of packages working and a bunch not working, it has to be my system is not configured correctly, not the packages themselves at fault right?

Comment: ok, some success. I managed to install some of the packages previously failing in general python domain successfully installing in a virtual environment. PyQt5 still not loading, along with some others. I need some other installation method than `pip` it would seem. Often it gets thrown at the creation of metadata or in another package, making a wheel. I think for Qt there will be some other way to install their tools, not sure about other packages.

Comment: more weirdness, used brew to attempt to install PyQt5 and it also failed. 

outside any virtual environments I created, I now (miraculously) have python 3.9.10 installed (not 3.8.2), when I ask python3 --version. Not sure how that happened. Now when I attempted `python3 -m pip install PyQt5` it works! some other modules still failing. when I try and use `pip` as a direct command Bash doesn't know it. Previously it did, `pip --version` would return v 22.n now when using pip as `python3 -m pip install…`  I'm told I'm using v21.3.1 and should update pip. such madness.